# Ruby Scan method, regex

Tags: regex, ruby

Hi Im trying to parse this string with scan method

```
test = "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/MB free=14791, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/MB free=9451, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/percent full=1.0"
```

I have to capture the path : `/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)`
and the number on percent full: `1.0`

I have tried with many regex but I can get it to work

```
testa = test.gsub(',', '')
r = testa.scan(/Disk\/File System\/\[((.*))\]\/percent full=([^[:space:]]+)/)
puts r
```

---Edit---

the string can have multiple ocurrences of of the FS and the percentage:

```
test = "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/MB free=14791, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/MB free=9451, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/percent full=1.0, Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/MB total=1974, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/MB total=10015, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/percent full=61.0, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/percent full=23.0, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/MB total=452543, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/MB free=426145, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/MB total=10015, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/MB free=3717, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/MB total=20030, Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/percent full=9.0, Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/MB free=1699, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/percent full=1.0, Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/MB total=3851, Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/percent full=0.0, Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/MB free=3851"
```

help please, thanks

Comment: You haven't said what return value is desired when there are "multiple ocurrences of of the FS and the percentage.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you can get it to work, then what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```rb
/Disk\/File System\/\[([^\]\[]*)\]\/percent full=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/lQy1OM3muV7ZV4) ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/FeU05w/1)). *Details*:

- `Disk\/File System\/\[` - a `Disk/File System/[` string
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, as many as possible
- `\]\/percent full=` - a `]/percent full=` text
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits.

[In Ruby](https://ideone.com/SevNb9):

```rb
test = "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/MB free=14791, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/MB free=9451, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/percent full=1.0, Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/MB total=1974, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/MB total=10015, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/percent full=61.0, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/percent full=23.0, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/MB total=452543, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/MB free=426145, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/MB total=10015, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/MB free=3717, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/MB total=20030, Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/percent full=9.0, Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/MB free=1699, Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/percent full=1.0, Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/MB total=3851, Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/percent full=0.0, Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/MB free=3851"
rx = /Disk\/File System\/\[([^\]\[]*)\]\/percent full=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
puts test.scan(rx)
```

Output:

```rb
[
   ["/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)", "1.0"],
   ["/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)", "61.0"],
   ["/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)", "23.0"],
   ["/dev/sda2 (/boot)", "9.0"],
   ["/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)", "1.0"],
   ["devtmpfs (/dev)", "0.0"]
]
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor I forgot to mention that I have to capture every ocurrence of the FS and the percentage, with you solution I only get one, sorry.

Comment: @Syirtblplmj I have revamped the solution that will now meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I will write the string as follows to clarify its structure.

```
test = "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/MB free=14791," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/MB free=9451," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/percent full=1.0," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/MB total=1974," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/MB total=10015, " +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/percent full=61.0," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/percent full=23.0, " +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/MB total=452543, " +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)]/MB free=426145," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/MB total=10015," +     
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)]/MB free=3717," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)]/MB total=20030," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/percent full=9.0," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/sda2 (/boot)]/MB free=1699," +
       "Disk/File System/[/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)]/percent full=1.0, " +
       "Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/MB total=3851, " +
       "Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/percent full=0.0, " +
       "Disk/File System/[devtmpfs (/dev)]/MB free=3851"
```

I assume you want to extract all pairs of paths and "percent full" values, disregarding paths that are not followed by "percent full".

You may write

```
r = /\bDisk\/File System\/\[([^\]]+)\]\/percent full=(\d+\.\d)/
```

```
test.scan(r)
  #=> [["/dev/mapper/rhel-opt (/opt)", "1.0"],
  #    ["/dev/mapper/rhel-root (/)", "61.0"],
  #    ["/dev/mapper/rhel-var (/var)", "23.0"],
  #    ["/dev/sda2 (/boot)", "9.0"],
  #    ["/dev/mapper/rhel-home (/home)", "1.0"],
  #    ["devtmpfs (/dev)", "0.0"]]
```

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    \b                     # assert a word break
    Disk\/File System\/\[  # match a string
    ([^\]]+)               # match 1 or more chars other than ']',
                           #   saved to capture group 1
    \]\/percent[ ]full=    # match a string
    (\d+\.\d)              # match one or more digits followed by '.', followed
                           #   by one digit, saved to capture group 2 
    /x                     # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note that in free-spacing mode the space between `percent` and `full` would be stripped out before the expression is parsed if it were not protected in some way. Enclosing the space in a character class, as I have done, is one of several ways of doing that.